# Stacked Bar Graph in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3Js.i am following this http://codepen.io/benlister/pres/bNeLQy for stacked bar graph.I am not sure how to make the y axis absolute.Here it is shown in % .I tried adding 
    `y.domain([0,500]);` 
It didnt work.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are talking about the % symbol, you have to change the tick format.

The code is this:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));
```

Just remove the `tickFormat`, or change it to the format you want.

But your problem is bigger than that: the y axis shows percent because the data is being transformed to percentages. This is the code that does the math:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
            var y0 = 0;

            d.rates = color.domain().map(function (name) {
                console.log();;
                return {
                    name: name,
                    y0: y0,
                    y1: y0 += +d[name],
                    amount: d[name]
                };
            });
            d.rates.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y0 /= y0;
                d.y1 /= y0;
            });
```

Check this example to see how to do it with absolute values:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line
`var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));`
to
`var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format("d"));`
for integer values on your y axis.

See [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting) for more details.